# Code highlight in vmware-clarity/Angular4 not working

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

So I'm trying to use the Code Highlight from the VMware Clarity project in my angular project. But I am having no succes in implementing it succesful.

I added these lines to my index.html as per documentation. But that only gives me errors.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/prismjs/themes/prism-solarizedlight.css">
<script src="node_modules/prismjs/prism.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/prismjs/components/prism-typescript.min.js"></script>
```

[image: Errors]
I then tried adding it to the scripts element in the angular.cli. To no avail.

I'm kinda lost on what to do next since documentation and answers are lacking..

[Edit] I do have prismjs installed with npm.

Comment: Do you have prismjs in your package.json and did you install all the dependencies?

Comment: Yes, i have prismjs, and @types/prismjs. Edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the stylesheets and the scripts in `angular-cli.json`

```
...
"styles": [
    ...
    "../node_modules/clarity-ui/clarity-ui.min.css",
    "../node_modules/prismjs/themes/prism-solarizedlight.css",
    ...
],
"scripts": [
    ...  
    "../node_modules/prismjs/prism.js",
    "../node_modules/prismjs/components/prism-typescript.min.js",
    ...
],
...
```

Refer to this file for more info:
https://github.com/vmware/clarity/blob/new-website/angular-cli.json#L19

Comment: Don't know why that didn't work before. But now it is showing a yellow box.
But code won't show when I define (clr-code-highlight="language-javascript")
and within the code tags I have {{code}}